# Remove cloned elements and add new ones

Tags: jquery, clone

I have two problems and can't find solution:

The code below is only an example to show my point.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#val1').val(1);
  $('#val2').val(2);
  $('#val3').val(3);
  var clone = $('#form2.form2:first').clone().appendTo($('#form2'));
  clone.find('#val1').val(11);
  clone.find('#val2').val(12);
  clone.find('#val3').val(13);
  var form1_clone = $('#form1.form1:first').clone().appendTo($('#form1'));
  form1_clone.find('#val1').val(21);
  form1_clone.find('#val2').val(22);
  form1_clone.find('#val3').val(23);
});
```

```html
<div id="form1">
  <table class="form1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Val 1</td>
        <td>Val 2</td>
        <td>Val 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="form2">
      <tr class="form2">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="val3" id="val3" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k194j8fh/)

#### Question 1:

How I can remove cloned element `form2` from cloned `form1`?

#### Question 2:

What is the way to add new clones `form2` in cloned element `form1` and fill them with values 31, 32, 33

Comment: The cloned elements have the same IDs as the originals.  This makes them unreferenceable (at least, by ID) as multiple elements with the same ID will have undefined behavior (jquery will attempt to return the first one on the page, but it is not guaranteed).  I suspect that if you wish to continue in this manner you need to remove the IDs and use only classes and hierarchical relationships (this, parent, child, sibling).

Answer (score 0):

For this cloning business it is better to have a clean template to clone from, so I suggest to do this:

- Create an invisible (`display: none`) template
- Clone it initially
- Then use it to clone parts of it (form1 / form2)

Also, as mentioned in the comment, it is better to use classes instead of IDs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var template = $('.template');

// Clone the main template
var tpl_clone = template.clone().show().insertAfter($('.template'));
tpl_clone.find('.val1').val(1);
tpl_clone.find('.val2').val(2);
tpl_clone.find('.val3').val(3);

// Add one more form2 to the cloned template
var form2_clone = template.find('.form2').clone().appendTo(tpl_clone.find('.wrap-form2'));
form2_clone.find('.val1').val(11);
form2_clone.find('.val2').val(12);
form2_clone.find('.val3').val(13);

//Q: How I can remove cloned element form2 from cloned form1?
//A: Don't insert it, clone from the clean template
var form1_clone = template.find('.form1:first').clone().appendTo(tpl_clone);
form1_clone.find('.val1').val(21);
form1_clone.find('.val2').val(22);
form1_clone.find('.val3').val(23);

//Q: What is the way to add new clones form2 in cloned element 
//   form1 and fill them with values 31, 32, 33
//A: Clone from the template and append to the form2 wrapper
var form2_clone2 = template.find('.form2').clone().appendTo(form1_clone.find('.wrap-form2'));
form2_clone2.find('.val1').val(31);
form2_clone2.find('.val2').val(32);
form2_clone2.find('.val3').val(33);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="template" style="display:none">
   <table class="form1">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Val 1</td>
     <td>Val 2</td>
     <td>Val 3</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="wrap-form2">
    <tr class="form2">
     <td><input type="text" name="val1" class="val1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="val2" class="val2"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="val3" class="val3"/></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```